# class selector that selects all elements with specific classes which are in the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

To clearify here is an example :

So we have

```
<div id="div1" class="a b c">
<div id="div2" class="a b c d">
<div id="div3" class="a b e f">
```

js:

```
var allClasses = ".a.b.c.d";

$(allClasses) // will select div2 and not div1 and div3
```

but i want to improve this script so that it will select div1 and div2 but not div3 because it in allClasses we have `.a.b.c.d`    and it matches div1 and div2 classes and it does not match div3  because in div3 there isnt class `d`
So all i want is to select all elements which classes match the string classes

Let me clearify a little bit more:

if `var allClasses = ".a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j";`

```
$( some implementation here using allClasses)
```

have to select elements with classes that does not miss in the allClasses variable
for example

```
<div id="div11" class="a b e f z"> // will not be selected
<div id="div12" class="a b e f g"> // will be selected
<div id="div13" class="a b e f omg"> // will not be selected
```

Comment: Based on what should it select the first div, that doesn't even have the class `d` ...?

Comment: In your example, selecting `$('.a.b.c')` will get div1 and div2 but not div3. Are there more complex criteria which you haven't mentioned?

Comment: im generating this string from button which populate this string with input values so i i cant know what the string is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to select all the elements that have one of the classes and then remove all the elements that have classes that aren't in your list:

```
// Turn ".a.b.c" into ".a,.b,.c"
var anyOfAllClasses = allClasses.replace(/\./g, ",.").substring(1);

// Retrieve all "candidates" and filter them
$(anyOfAllClasses).filter(function() {

    // Require that each of their classes appears in your list
    return this.className.split(/\s+/).reduce(function(currentlyAcceptable, nextClass) {
        return currentlyAcceptable && (allClasses + ".").indexOf("." + nextClass + ".") >= 0
    });
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5hnmpqa/2/)**

It's also worth noting that this won't work in IE8 due to my use of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). You could of course do a regular loop instead if you need to support IE8.

Comment: gosh so hard for js learner to implement im shocked jquery does not have a function for this its so simple problem

so simple if some of the classes does not match in the selector it just dont get selected

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov There might be a simpler way but I don't know of any. Doing anything beyond the basics (e.g., adding/removing) with classes can get tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that you have always a given order of classes in your class attribute you can use an attribute selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 

  $('[class="a"], [class="a b"], [class="a b c"], [class="a b c d"]').css('color', 'green');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="a b c">DIV 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="a b c d">DIV 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="a b c e f">DIV 3</div>
```

I would create an automate function which will create such selector for me using given yours '.a.b.c.d' and returning the one above. It would be very simple to create such function. Then this will much DOM elements containing exactly one of the given combination.

Comment: You could simplify this with `$('.a, .a.b, .a.b.c, .a.b.c.d')`.

Comment: This will match `div3` as well

Comment: so if i have string containing 10 classes the final string will be 55 separated class combinations

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1" class="a b c">
<div id="div2" class="a b c d">
<div id="div3" class="a b e f">
<script>
$('.a, .b, .c, .d')
</script>
```